# If $R$ is a commutative Artinian ring and $a\in R$, is $A_M:=\{f_a\mid f_a:M\to M,m\mapsto ma\}$ an Artinian ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals, artinian

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $M$ an $R$-module.  The mapping $$\begin{array}{ll}R&\to& \text{End}_{\Bbb Z}(M)\\a&\mapsto &f_a\,,\end{array}$$ which associates with $a\in R$ the homothety $$f_a(m)= ma\quad\forall m\in M\,,$$ is an isomorphism of $R$ into the ring $\text{End}_{\Bbb Z}(M)$ of endomorphisms of the additive group of $M$.

> **Questions.**
>
> (1) If $R$ is Artinian, is $A_M:=\{f_a\mid f_a:M\to M\}$ an Artinian ring.
>
> (2) Does $A_M$ have a prime ideal?

Comment: What is $A$ supposed to be? Just another $R$ right? That's what looks to be the case...  In general this mapping isn't going to be *onto* $End_\mathbb Z(M)$, I don't think... do you just mean *into*?

Comment: "the ring of endomorphisms of the additive group of $R$" doesnt' seem to appear anywhere... looks like that $R$ should be an $M$?  There is a lot to clean up here.

Comment: Even if I guess I understand the question, aren't both questions trivial?  $A_M$ is a homomorphic image of an Artinian ring, and it has identity.  So it's obviously Artinian and has prime ideals...

Comment: I have made the corrections

Comment: One should define $f_a(m)$ to be $am$, not $ma$, since $M$ is implicitly assumed to be a left $R$-module (after all, any right $R$-module is also a left $R$-module if $R$ is commutative). If $R$ is not commutative, then the domain of the homomorphism to the endomorphism ring would need to be changed to $R^{\mathrm{op}}$ if $M$ is a right $R$-module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map you're suggesting isn't an isomorphism unless $M$ is faithful.

But anyway,  $A_M$ is a homomorphic image of an Artinian ring, so it is also Artinian.  Any ring with an identity (different from zero) has prime ideals, so of course this ring will too, as long as it is nonzero.  In that case its identity is $f_1$.

Comment: I think you need nonzero identity to get prime ideals. So if M is the zero module the ring will be the trivial ring and hence lack prime ideals.

Comment: @TokenToucan It's true, but won't be an issue if the user really does want a faithful module.